# Drop shadow of node with pgfplot inside

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, nesting, shadows

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[drop shadow,draw,fill=green] {
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
   \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
};
\path [use as bounding box] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

The problem is now that the plot has also a drop shadow. How can I avoid this? I tried to use `fill` either in `pre`- or `postaction` or changing the pgfplot background to white but that dind't help.

Comment: Why are you including the `tikzpicture` with the plot inside the `\node`? Can you describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to connect different nodes in a flow diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner nodes will inherit the shadow; that's why is not, generally speaking, a good idea to nest `tikzpicrure`s.

You can use a background layer to add the colored background:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
   \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw[drop shadow,draw,fill=green] 
    ([yshift=3pt]current bounding box.north west) rectangle ([xshift=3pt]current bounding box.south east);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a comment it has been requested to have two plots, each one with a colored background and a drop shadow and both connected with an arrow; this can be done by saving the plots in boxes (safe method for nesting `tikzpicture`s) and then using nodes to place them and draw the arrow. An example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\newsavebox\myboxa
\newsavebox\myboxb

\savebox\myboxa{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
   \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw[drop shadow,draw,fill=green] 
    ([yshift=3pt]current bounding box.north west) rectangle ([xshift=3pt]current bounding box.south east);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\savebox\myboxb{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
   \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (0.4,0.6) (0.7,0.2) (1,1)};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw[drop shadow,draw,fill=green] 
    ([yshift=3pt]current bounding box.north west) rectangle ([xshift=3pt]current bounding box.south east);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {\usebox\myboxa};
\node[right=of a] (b) {\usebox\myboxb};
\draw[->] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution! What would be the correct way to connect 2 nodes with pgfplots inside, instead of nesting the pgfplots inside the nodes?

Comment: @Reza I am not sure what you are asking. Do you have two plots and you want to connect some points from one of them to some points of the other?

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation. I have two nodes with a pgfplot inside and I want just to have drop shadow on every node and connect them with an arrow: `\draw[->] (node1) -- (node2);`

Comment: @Reza Ah, now I see. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: cool thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Since which version is this possible?

Comment: @Reza I wouldn't know exactly, nut it definitively should work with version 2.10. Is it something not working for you?

Comment: no it's alright, I was just searching for such a feature quiet a time. Is there even apossibility to declare a savebox inside the document (in combination with the standalone package).