# Standalone package, preserve preamble

Tags: macros, standalone

Is it in a way possible to preserve parts of a preamble of a standalone document?
For example when I have a savebox or a macro inside it and don't want to repeat it in the preamble of my main document. Here a mini example `mypicture.tex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw] (b) at (0,2) {\usebox\mybox};
    \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document
```

So when I include this file inside my main document I don't want to reassign my savebox but instead reuse the one from the standalone file.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{standalone}
% No redeclaration of the savebox here
\begin{document}
  \input{mypicture.tex}
\end{document}
```

I didn't found any mechanism in the `standalone` manual but perhaps there is an easy solution to this problem.

Comment: Would it help to put the `\newsavebox` after `\begin{document}`? Or asked in another way: Is there a reason why it must be in the preamble?

Comment: as far as I understand is this not possible because nesting of environments is disallowed (and gives a missing `\endgroup` error)

Comment: See [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157303/6563). It works with your MWE.

Answer (score 7):

The [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) package has a `subpreambles` option that preserves the preambles. Your MWE seems to have a couple of small issues (it is missing a `}` in `\end{document}` and you never load the `tikz` package. Fixing those two issues and adding the package option

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
% No redeclaration of the savebox here
\begin{document}
  \input{mypicture.tex}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw] (b) at (0,2) {\usebox\mybox};
    \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that is in a way what I was looking for. But there's no fine grained control, to allow parts of the sub preambles to be included in the main preamble?

Comment: @Reza `\ifstandalone` may be able to give you the control that you need, but it is not clear from your MWE what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The most recommended solution by me only for the best practitioners.

### Step 1: Create a package

Put everything you use across many input files in a single package, e.g., `mygraphiclib.sty`.

```
% mygraphiclib.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mygraphiclib}[2014/02/03 v0.01 LaTeX package for my graphic library]
\RequirePackage{tikz}

% mybox
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% myBox
\newcommand\myBox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\endinput
% mygraphiclib.sty
```

Use `\newcommand` so you can avoid defining the same macro name accidentally.

### Step 2: Create child input files

You can separate each diagram into its own input file by using `standalone` class. 
This input file of course needs the `mygraphiclib.sty` if you want to make use of the macros in `mygraphiclib.sty`.

```
% child.tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mygraphiclib}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
        \node[draw] (b) at (0,2) {\usebox\mybox};
        \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

During the development phase, you might need to recompile this input file many times so separation of concern really helps you to reduce the compilation time. Imagine if you put all graphic code in the main input file,  you will waste much time to compile a bunch of diagrams every time you modify just a single diagram.

### Step 3: Create the main input file

The main input file just needs to load `mygraphiclib.sty` and `standalone` (or `docmute`)  to make use the child input files.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mygraphiclib}
\usepackage{standalone}% or \usepackage{docmute}

\begin{document}
\input{child}
\end{document}
```

### Simulation all in one

The following input file simulates all of the steps given above as a single input file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mygraphiclib.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mygraphiclib}[2014/02/03 v0.01 LaTeX package for my graphic library]
\RequirePackage{tikz}

% mybox
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% myBox
\def\myBox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\endinput
% mygraphiclib.sty
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{child.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mygraphiclib}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
        \node[draw] (b) at (0,2) {\usebox\mybox};
        \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{mygraphiclib}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\input{child}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation in [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157274/standalone-package-preserve-preamble/157303#comment360097_157274) works with your MWE.

When you put the `\newsavebox` after `\begin{document}` it works:

There are some minor additional errors:

mypicture.tex missed the closing `}` in `\end{document}`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw] (b) at (0,2) {\usebox\mybox};
    \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

your mainfile missed the `\usepackage{tikz}`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \input{mypicture.tex}
\end{document}
```

---

Update: I detected a problem when I run `mypicture.tex`. This version solved the problem, but I think a better solution (without code repetition) should be possible:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
 \ifstandalone
    \newsavebox\mybox
    \savebox\mybox{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\fi
\begin{document}
 \ifstandalone
 \else
    \newsavebox\mybox
    \savebox\mybox{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw] (b) at (0,2) {\usebox\mybox};
    \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange your example gives me an missing `\endgroup` inserted error.

Comment: I think this example basically reinforces that in standalone mode, we must put the box definition inside the preamble?

Answer (score 0):

First file:

```
%% mypicture.tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{temp.tex}
    \tikz\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw] (b) at (0,2) {\input{temp}};
    \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Second file:

```
%%% myfile.tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \input{mypicture.tex}
\end{document}
```

Running `mypicture.tex` and `myfile.tex` has the output  `myfile.pdf`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But this approach is not working with `savebox`. Nesting of environments causes an error.

Comment: @Reza: Make a complete example, which shows what exactly you want. It is also possible to create the standalone file from within another file.

Comment: @Herbert Ok I adjusted my example, hope it's clear now

Comment: @Reza: see my edited answer

Comment: Good idea, but it's not working with a `\savebox` inside the `temp.tex` file

Comment: @Reza: again: Why do you need a savebox?? The main purpose  is to write it into an external file _instead_ of using a  savebox!

Comment: @Herbert see my question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157191/drop-shadow-of-node-with-pgfplot-inside a savebox allows me to nest tikzpictures safely

Comment: that is the same as the external file does!

Comment: yes but when you apply a drop shadow to the box it will also be applied to the plot, with savebox this does not happen.